# Document,text format

Tags: text, format, document

to my project i need document editor for many types of documents(tabular data, invoices, letters, some formulars,...) and i am looking for text format and editor to acompish my task

- is there some MS Word like format?
- I know for example rtf, I need formating, invissible comment will be veeery good
- open format
- same 3th p. editor will be good

I found some solutions, rtf is the most frequent

please have you same suggestions or personal experiences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check ODF (Open Document Format) for a free and open document format that can handle text, spreadsheets and many other things.

See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) for references.

[OpenOffice](http://openoffice.org/) is one of the many products that do support ODF.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a text format or a text editor ? I guess this is a text format...

Many exist (other than RTF that you already mentionned) such as:

- HTML
- TeX/LaTeX
- nroff/troff
- Postscript

Many (more or less) wysiwyg editors are available for the first two.